# Let $f$ be a continuous function on [$0, 1$] with $f(0) =1$. Let $ G(a) = 1/a ∫_0^a f(x)\,dx$ then which of the followings are true?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on [$0, 1$] with $f(0) =1$. Let $ G(a) = 1/a ∫_0^af(x)\,dx$ then which of the followings are true?

1. $\lim_{(a\to 0)} G(a)=1/2$
2. $\lim_{(a\to0)} G(a)=1$
3. $\lim_{(a\to 0)} G(a)=0$
4. The limit $\lim_{(a\to 0)G(a)}$ does not exist.

I am completely stuck on it. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $G(a)$ is the mean (or average) value of the function on the interval $[0,a]$. Here’s an intuitive argument that should help you see what’s going on. The function $f$ is continuous, and $f(0)=1$, so when $x$ is very close to $0$, $f(x)$ must be close to $1$. Thus, for $a$ close to $0$, $f(x)$ should be close to $1$ for every $x\in[0,a]$, and therefore its mean value should also be close to $1$.

From that it should be easy to pick out the right answer, but it would also be a good exercise for you to try to prove that the answer really **is** right.

Comment: Sorry for asking but should I delete my answer while yours and other's answers are in details?

Comment: @Babak: I don’t see any real reason to do so: I upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks Brian for supporting others. You are really our kind father here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use l'Hospital's rule for $\lim_{a\to 0}G(a)$. We see that $G(a)\to 1$ when $a$ tends to zero.

Comment: L'Hopital to the rescue once again... $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @amWhy: Amy, I think, it is better he had change his family name to L'Hospital. Cause it really is needed in emergency cases in limits. :D

Answer (score 1):

With the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), you can express
\begin{align}
&\int_0^a f(x) \, dx = F(a)-F(0)
\\ \Leftrightarrow &\frac1a\int_0^a f(x) \, dx = \frac{F(a)-F(0)}{a}=G(a)
\end{align}
If you now want to evaluate $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} G(a)$ you get
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} G(a) =\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(a)-F(0)}{a}= ?
\end{align}
Does the above formulation remind you of something?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you let $f(x)=\cos{x}$, then $f(0)=1$ and $\int_0^a f(x) dx=\sin{a}$.  We know that $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\sin(a)}{a}=1$$ as a common identity.  So if this is supposed to hold for all continuous functions on $[0,1]$, then statement $2$ must be true.

This helps you determine the answer quickly; proving it, of course, is a different matter.